# html iframe just show nothing

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I'm just want to show a web page within a webpage by using the iframe. I've try just a simple code below:

```
<iframe src="http://edition.cnn.com/" id="i_frame"></iframe>
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/zdnb88us/)

But nothing shows up? Any ideas why?

Answer (score 2):

If you look in your browser console you will see that it is being blocked since the fiddle is on `https` and the iframe is on `http` protocol.

It works fine if you load fiddle on `http` protocol.

[**Working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/zdnb88us/1/)

for more information read up on [Mixed Content Security](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Security/MixedContent) in browsers

Comment: That's in JSFIDDLE. But on my local machine, when I want to show "www.airasia.com" this error comes out in the console: Refused to display 'airasia.com/my/en/home.page?cid=1'; in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'. Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: nothing you can do about it if the page you load sets frame buster headers. That is their perogative to not let you load their page into your site. This is also easily researched

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the Javascript console? [image]

So, the browser blocks it because you are loading HTTP site in a HTTPS site.

Comment: That's in JSFIDDLE. But on my local machine, when I want to show "www.airasia.com" this error comes out in the console: Refused to display 'airasia.com/my/en/home.page?cid=1'; in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'. Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: @Coolguy That is a security feature that cnn.com is using so nobody can use it in an iframe. It wont be easy / straight forward to have it in an iframe in my opinion.